# WaitForSeconds не работает (unity3d)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не пойму почему не работает, все правильно сделал, по примеру, но нет.

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKey("1")) //change weapon
    {
        currect_weapon = pistolprefab;
        previos_weapon = autorifleprefab;
        weapon_active = true;
        weapon_damage = 10;
        ammo_amount = 7;
        defaultammo_amount = 7;
        reload_time = 3;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("2")) {
        currect_weapon = autorifleprefab;
        previos_weapon = pistolprefab;
        weapon_active = true;
        weapon_damage = 20;
        ammo_amount = 30;
        defaultammo_amount = 30;
        reload_time = 6;
    }
    if (ammo_amount < 0) {
        ammo_amount = 0;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)) //shooting
    {
        --ammo_amount;
        StartCoroutine(Wait(10));
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("r")) //reload
    {
        if (ammo_amount == 0) {
            StartCoroutine(Wait(2));
            ammo_amount = defaultammo_amount;
        }
    }
}
IEnumerator Wait(int waitTime) {
    yield
    return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
}
```

Comment: @Markus  Lolovis, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д. Что конкретно вы хотели реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

`StartCoroutine`, как следует из названия, запускает сопрограмму и *не ждет ее окончания*. Поэтому делать вызов `StartCoroutine` чтобы подождать - бессмысленно. Вместо этого надо преобразовать функцию `Update` в сопрограмму.

Answer (score -1):

WaitForSeconds заставляет метод подождать перед выполнением некоторое время. То есть, если вам нужна задежка перед каким-либо действием надо использовать WaitForSeconds таким образом

```
IEnumerator Wait(int waitTime) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    // Выполнить некоторый код через waitTime секунд
    // с момента вызова метода Wait(int waitTime)
}
```